# Get number of months from numeric year

Tags: sql-server

In my application , which is based on loan process, i request the no. of tenors in year from the user.
from the given year i convert it into no. of months.

for example if user gives tenor is 1.1, then no of months is calculated as follow as in query,

```
Declare @repayment_in_yrs numeric(10,2)
SET @repayment_in_yrs = 1.1
select ((@repayment_in_yrs % 1)*100)/10
Select ((@repayment_in_yrs - (@repayment_in_yrs %1)) * 12)
Select (((@repayment_in_yrs % 1)*100)/10) + ((@repayment_in_yrs - (@repayment_in_yrs %1)) * 12)
```

The output is 12+1 = 13 months.

if i get the user input as 1.10 then the result should be 12+10 = 22 months.
But the output is 13.

I can use the sbustring function to split that as 1,10 and then calculate it.

But i am looking for other better solutions.

Please provide your suggestions.

Comment: always tag the version of software. this helps to get better answer

Comment: Is the variable really passed over as `numeric(10,2)`? The trailing `0` will get lost,  `1.1 == 1.10`...

Comment: Thanks for all who replied. I will change my data type to varchar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
DECLARE @repayment_in_yrs NUMERIC(10,2) =  1.11

SELECT
    (CAST(@repayment_in_yrs AS INT)*12)+
    CASE 
        WHEN PARSENAME(@repayment_in_yrs,1) IN (11,12)
            THEN PARSENAME(@repayment_in_yrs,1)
        ELSE PARSENAME(@repayment_in_yrs,1)/10 END
```

But this will not work for 1.1 and 1.10.

So, In That case, you may try changing the Datatype to VARCHAR from DECIMAL. and try the following

```
DECLARE @repayment_in_yrs VARCHAR(20) =  1.1

;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        NumVal = CAST(@repayment_in_yrs AS DECIMAL(10,2)),
        CharVal = CAST(@repayment_in_yrs AS VARCHAR(20))
)
SELECT
    (CAST(NumVal AS INT)*12)+
    CASE 
        WHEN PARSENAME(CharVal,1) IN (10,11,12)
            THEN PARSENAME(CharVal,1)
        ELSE PARSENAME(NumVal,1)/10 END
    FROM CTE
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But this lies on my requirement 1.1 and 1.10.

Comment: I have added one more solution please try that

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is, that a `numeric(10,2)` with a value of `1.1` will show up as `1.10`. Trailing zeros have no meaning here...

It is impossible to distinguish `1.1` and `1.10` if you deal with it as a number...

So I assume, that your values exist as strings somewhere. In this case you can use a trick with XML to get hands on the first and the second part separately:

```
DECLARE @testValues TABLE(Val VARCHAR(10), ShouldBe VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @testValues VALUES('1','1 year')
                             ,('1.0','1 year')
                             ,('1.1','1 year 1 month')
                             ,('1.10','1 year 10 months')
                             ,('.1','1 month')
                             ,('0.1','one month')
                             ,('3.12','3 years 12 months (one more year)');
SELECT tv.*
      ,  ISNULL(Part.value('/x[1]/text()[1]','int'),0) * 12 
       + ISNULL(Part.value('/x[2]/text()[1]','int'),0) AS ComputedMonths 
FROM @testValues AS tv
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(tv.Val,'.','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)) AS Splittable(Part);
```

The result

```
+------+-----------------------------------+----------------+
| Val  | ShouldBe                          | ComputedMonths |
+------+-----------------------------------+----------------+
| 1    | 1 year                            | 12             |
+------+-----------------------------------+----------------+
| 1.0  | 1 year                            | 12             |
+------+-----------------------------------+----------------+
| 1.1  | 1 year 1 month                    | 13             |
+------+-----------------------------------+----------------+
| 1.10 | 1 year 10 months                  | 22             |
+------+-----------------------------------+----------------+
| .1   | 1 month                           | 1              |
+------+-----------------------------------+----------------+
| 0.1  | one month                         | 1              |
+------+-----------------------------------+----------------+
| 3.12 | 3 years 12 months (one more year) | 48             |
+------+-----------------------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: This is why I deleted my answer.  I realized 6 months would be presented as 1.6  not 1.06    I always appreciate the completeness of your answers.